# Which resources to become a certified Magento developer?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am eager to become a good Magento developer. I have done a little customization in Magento such as,

1. customization in theme.
2. create custom tabs in admin side.
3. understand dir structures of magento.

I did this under the guidance of my senior company mate and I use Magento's knowlege base as well as a Magento cookbook. But now I want to do some practical exercises, for that I need some good resources.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From your question I don't think agile is necessarily what you're looking for.  If you'd like to learn to work in an agile fashion that should be something you learn completely separate from Magento.  If you'd like to learn more about creating custom extensions and modifying things past theming I'd recommend Magento's Fundamentals of Magento Development training.  Its free online right now and has about 40 hours of video content - http://www.magentocommerce.com/training/on-demand

This should teach you almost everything else an experienced magento dev would know (past theming).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a general overview of all Magento topics you could use the studyguide for magento certification ([studyguide](http://www.magestudyguide.com/)). Working with the sourcecode and answering the questions myself helped me a lot to understand how Magento works and I improved myself in topics I didn't know that much before. There are even blogs who explain this topics ([magestore](http://blog.magestore.com/category/magento-certification/)).